# Only some fields from Firebase are transferred to my code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've spent hours trying to figure out why some of the fields from a document in Firestore won't transfer to my code.

Can you please help me to identify what's wrong with my code and how I should change it to make it work?

[This is what my Firebase Database looks like](https://ibb.co/tLX1yqH)

(And yes, the bus numbers are purposely saved as Strings)

I was trying to use the getValue method to read the data from Firebase as shown in the code below:

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BusDrivers");

  // Getting all of the registered bus drivers' information
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : datasnapshot.getChildren()) {
                BusDriver busDriver = snapshot.getValue(BusDriver.class);
                busDrivers.add(busDriver);
            }
        }
```

However, only some of the fields are transferred to the busDriver object. When I call `busDriver.getDriverFirstName()`, I accurately get a result...

[image: Don is returned after calling for the driver's first name]

But when I call busDriver.getAmBusRoute(), I get this for some reason...

[image: N/A]

Here's the code of the BusDriver class as well.

```
public class BusDriver {
private final String busDriverID;
private final String amBusRoute;
private final String pmBusRoute;
private final String driverFirstName;
private final String driverMiddleName;
private final String driverLastName;

public BusDriver() {
    this.busDriverID = "N/A";
    this.amBusRoute = "N/A";
    this.pmBusRoute = "N/A";
    this.driverFirstName = "N/A";
    this.driverMiddleName = "N/A";
    this.driverLastName = "N/A";
}

public BusDriver(String busDriverID, String amBusRoute, String pmBusRoute, String driverFirstName, String driverMiddleName,
                 String driverLastName) {
    this.busDriverID = busDriverID;
    this.amBusRoute = amBusRoute;
    this.pmBusRoute = pmBusRoute;
    this.driverFirstName = driverFirstName;
    this.driverMiddleName = driverMiddleName;
    this.driverLastName = driverLastName;
}

public String getBusDriverID() { return busDriverID; }

public Object getAmBusRoute() { return amBusRoute; }

public Object getPmBusRoute() { return pmBusRoute; }

public String getDriverFirstName() { return driverFirstName; }

public String getDriverMiddleName() { return driverMiddleName; }

public String getDriverLastName() { return driverLastName; }
```

}

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/7k407nS/Screenshot-2021-11-04-225815.png), you are using Firestore, but your code tries to read data from the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), and this is not correct. To solve this problem, you have to add Firestore to your project. To achieve this, please check the official documentation regarding how to [get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java_2).

Right after you do that, to read the data you can use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference busDriversRef = db.collection("BusDrivers");
busDriversRef..get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                BusDriver busDriver = document.toObject(BusDriver.class);
                busDrivers.add(busDriver);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an `Object` from these getters. You should be returning `String` here.

```java
public Object getAmBusRoute() { return amBusRoute; }

public Object getPmBusRoute() { return pmBusRoute; }
```

Comment: If this doesn't fix your problem, please specify exactly which fields are missing from your result.

Comment: Alex's answer fixed my issue but this was also something that I missed. Thank you!